# CSS - Aligning Sortable Lists to Center

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the example from https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists , but I want to make the two lists in the middle of the page.
I've tried many different methods, but nothing seems to work properly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; */
}

#version-editor {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
}

#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="version-editor">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the above example works fine and show the lists in the middle of page ! `#version-editor { margin: 0 auto; }` will do the magic

Comment: The version-editor  is already centered, the problem is, that the two list arent

Comment: see updated answer please

Comment: yep, it works!  that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added `text-align: center;` to `#version-editor`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; */
}

#version-editor {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  text-align: center; /* added */
}

#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto; /* added */
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block; /* remove float and added this line */
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="version-editor">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>
```